# Migratordotnet creating initial migration

Tags: c#, database, database-migration, migratordotnet

I'm trying to use [migratordotnet](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) for existing database. My database has around 100 tables and I'm trying to generate initial migration.

I've tried using

```
C:\migrations>Migrator.Console.exe SqlServer "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=my_database;Integrated Security = True;" MigracijeBaze.dll -dump InitialMigration.cs
```

Unfortinutely, generated migration has every column with typeof(string). Int, DateTime, Decimal columns are converted to string. 
For example, for table Godine

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Godine](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirmaID] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Godina] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BazaSifri] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BazaPodataka] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Godine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

is generated migration

```
Database.AddTable("Godine",
    new Column("ID", typeof(String)),
    new Column("FirmaID", typeof(String)),
    new Column("Godina", typeof(String)),
    new Column("BazaSifri", typeof(String)),
    new Column("BazaPodataka", typeof(String)),
);
```

Am I doing something wrong? What are the best practices for doing initial migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. I've downloaded source code and used debugger.
It seems that dump option is not completely implemented.

```
public virtual Column[] GetColumns(string table)
{
    List<Column> columns = new List<Column>();
    using (
        IDataReader reader =
            ExecuteQuery(
                String.Format("select COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE from information_schema.columns where table_name = '{0}'", table)))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Column column = new Column(reader.GetString(0), DbType.String);
            string nullableStr = reader.GetString(1);
            bool isNullable = nullableStr == "YES";
            column.ColumnProperty |= isNullable ? ColumnProperty.Null : ColumnProperty.NotNull;

            columns.Add(column);
        }
    }

    return columns.ToArray();
}
```

Database type is hard coded. I'll just call sql script for my first migration. Related Issue is [on the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/issues/detail?id=20&q=dump)